# CORS блокирует запрос

Tags: cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://212.42.106.72/api/v1/districts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Да, Вы абсолютно правы, CORS блокирует запрос. Сервер, к которому происходит обращение, должен передавать [заголовок](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), разрешающий такой запрос.

Comment: Если запрос с `withCredentials`, то сервер должен вернуть два заголовка: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` с указанием **конкретного** домена, и `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.